# Can GTK work with a readline like library?

Tags: c, gtk, readline, editline

Is it possible for a graphical GTK program, to also have a "command line interface" like those provided by [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), [editline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise)?

How to deal with blocking gtk_main() calls, and blocking loop steps from those libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to integrate a library such as GNU readline with a graphical program. The simplest option is to spawn a thread dedicated for readline, and communicate with the GUI thread using `g_idle_add` (which is thread-safe).

If you don't want to use threads, you can use the GIO machinery (`g_io_channel_unix_new()` and `g_io_add_watch()`) to instruct the GTK main loop notify you of pending input, and invoke readline using the [altnernate interface](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC41) designed for use as event loop callback. Python's readline support and PyGTK make use of these features to enable the following, all in one thread:

```
>>> import gtk
>>> w = gtk.Window()
>>> w.add(gtk.Label("foo"))
>>> w.show_all()       # at this point, a window with label is shown
```

A different question, however, is whether you *want* your program to sport a command-line interface based on terminal emulation in the 21st century. In GTK you have a multiline editing facility that far exceeds readline(), it's called a `GtkTextView`. It is quite straightforward (and, I might add, fun) to use it to build a command-line-like facility which has no problems with copy-paste, multiline editing, Unicode, colors, proportional fonts, embedded images, or with working on Windows — and which doesn't rely on arcane terminal codes to boot.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will try this. My program can be customized with scheme scripts. A CLI can help me to debug and test those scripts easily, and even to run the program without a graphical interface.

Comment: @azmeuk The infrastructure is there - if you have a working understanding of event-driven programming, you can easily make readline and GTK cooperate. In my opinion a modern program should also support a true GUI REPL that doesn't depend on terminal emulation, in the manner of browsers' developer consoles.